# Glow on image except a certain div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

So I have an orange glow on my image which I would like everywhere except inside the bottom div which contains a title.

Shortened version of how it's build up

```
<div class="navbar-header"> <!-- Has a background image in css which is the base image -->
    <div class="glow-orange"> <!-- Has a background color: rgba(247, 147, 29, 0.4) -->
        <div class="title"> <!-- Is being positioned bottom in the middle -->
            Title
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a really simple image for the visualization of this setup. Blue would be my image with the glow. They grey bar is transparent. I want the part of th image behind the grey bar to be the original color of the image instead of the orange glow.

[image: Visualization]

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I'm using the bootstrap framework incase that might have some features that makes this easier / doable.

Comment: Please show *complete* markup, that would include the CSS.

Comment: @Scott Am I missing something important? This is just a small part of my complete website. No offense, because I'd post some css, but my css is quite a mess and I did already explain the way I setup the glow and the image which are the important parts right?

Comment: post the relevant  CSS code for your problem. not all of it.

Comment: @GerritIest how can anyone troubleshoot CSS issues without seeing the relevant CSS?

Comment: @GerritIest, you need to make an [MCVE] so that we can see your issue and try to fix it.  With what you have provided we are unable to help you and any solution would be a guess

Comment: @Pete I get that, but I'm just explaining my setup. It's not necessarily a problem I've in my setup. It's something that I just can't figure out how to do.

Comment: From what I gather, basically you want a hole in your div parent where the title is.  This currently isn't possible unless you use a not very well supported css3 clipping mask or make an svg overlay http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20205503/cutting-a-hole-in-a-parent-element-with-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to do this is to use large `box-shadow` on title and `overflow: hidden` on parent element.

```css
.navbar-header {
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  background: url('http://www.lenntech.com/images/Home/Waterdrop775.png');
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.glow-orange {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}
.title {
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 150px rgba(247, 147, 29, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar-header">
  <div class="glow-orange">
    <div class="title">Title</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for exactly understanding what I wanted and delivering that!